# Cannot echo colored text when inserting in status bar in dwm

Tags: linux, fedora, escape-characters, echo, dwm

I'm using Fedora 18. I'm trying to create a custom status bar in dwm. Now what I'm thinking of is to check if the battery is under a certain level, the background of the battery region in the status bar will be red.

The problem is, when this condition is true, I get a different result.

What I expected this to be shown inside the status bar with a red background:

```
(red bg: Discharging, 50%) | 04:21:20 AM 29/06/2013
```

But I get :

[image: ss of taskbar]

Here's my startup script :

```
#!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 # Created By Rafael Adel
  4 
  5 # This script is to start dwm with customizations needed
  6 
  7 
  8 while true;do
  9         datestr=`date +"%r %d/%m/%Y"`
 10         batterystr=`acpi | grep -oP "([a-zA-Z]*), ([0-9]*)%"`
 11         batterystate=`echo $batterystr | grep -oP "[a-zA-Z]*"`
 12         batterypercent=`echo $batterystr | grep -oP "[0-9]*"`
 13 
 14 
 15         if [ $batterypercent -le 90 ]
 16         then
 17                 finalstr="`echo -e "\033[41m${batterystr}\033[0m | $datestr"`"
 18         else
 19                 finalstr="$batterystr | $datestr"
 20         fi
 21                 xsetroot -name "$finalstr"
 22         sleep 1
 23 done &
 24 
 25 xbindkeys -f /etc/xbindkeysrc
 26 
 27 exec dwm
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

dwm does not have the capability to draw colored text in its status bar. If you want to fix this then you will need to modify [`drw.c:drw_text()`](http://git.suckless.org/dwm/tree/drw.c#n143) in the dwm source code.

Comment: Do you mean that, i need to do what i did in the script above but in C in this method ? Or just add it in that file?

Comment: You will need to rewrite that function in order to parse and interpret the escape codes.

Comment: Or, you could use the [statuscolors patch](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/statuscolors) on the suckless wiki...

Comment: @jasonwryan: That will give you a little bit of control over the color (and for this question, that little bit of control *will* be enough), but won't be enough to use even a partial set of escape codes.

Comment: Yes; is that a statement of disagreement, or a clarification? I mentioned it becasue I thought the OP would find it easier than starting from scratch...

Comment: A bit of both. I agree that it is an answer to the question, but I disagree that it counters my answer and the asker's original attempt.

Comment: It was never intended as a counter, but a complement. That's why it is a comment (and I upvoted your answer).